# How can i Bind data to new bindings

Tags: vb.net

error message "Child list for field dbo cannot be created" in last line code

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    ds1.Reset()
    con1 = New SqlConnection(Strcon)
    con1.Open()
    strsql1 = "SELECT * FROM dbo.rasmi where Personel_ID=123456"
    da1 = New SqlDataAdapter(strsql1, con1)
    da1.Fill(ds1, "dbo.rasmi")
    con1.Close()
    DataGridView1.DataBindings.Clear()
    DataGridView1.DataBindings.Add(New Binding("datasource", ds1, "dbo.rasmi"))
End Sub
```

Comment: That's not how you bind to a `DataGridView`.  You simply assign the `DataTable` to the `DataSource` property, or else assign the name of the `DataTable` to the `DataMember` and the `DataSet` to the `DataSource`.  You should learn the difference between complex and simple data-binding.  Also, don't use a `DataSet` if you're only using one `DataTable`.  Just use a `DataTable`.

Comment: I want do simple above code please guide me to debug error in this code if you khnow, thanks

Comment: No, you don't want to do simple data-binding.  It's not about simple being easy and complex being hard.  You do what is correct and if you want to display the contents of a `DataTable` in a `DataGridView` then you need to implement complex data-binding.  I told you what to do.  Do it.

Comment: I am beginner please help me by editing this code

Comment: I just want to khnow why this code not work not anything else

Comment: Anybody knows how can i use this code and why this error shown but in vs2015 not shown this error in other project likne this

Comment: You can't use that code because it's wrong.  Use the right code.  I've told you what the right code would include.

Comment: it is correct in my training example i am confused why do not answer in my project

Answer (score 0):

```
Imports System.Threading
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Public Class Form2
Dim Strcon As String = "Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=Pooyesh_Reprt;Persist Security 
Info=True;User ID=sa;Password=789456321"
Dim con1 As SqlConnection
Dim strsql1 As String = ""
Dim da1 As SqlDataAdapter
Dim ds1 As New DataSet

Private Sub Form2_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
Dim TypeOfLanguage = New System.Globalization.CultureInfo("fa") ' or "fa-IR" for  b  
Farsi(Iran) 
InputLanguage.CurrentInputLanguage = InputLanguage.FromCulture(TypeOfLanguage)
End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
ds1.Reset()
con1 = New SqlConnection(Strcon)
con1.Open()
strsql1 = "SELECT * FROM dbo.rasmi where Personel_ID=123456"
da1 = New SqlDataAdapter(strsql1, con1)
da1.Fill(ds1, "dbo.rasmi")
con1.Close()
DataGridView1.DataBindings.Clear()
DataGridView1.DataBindings.Add(New Binding("datasource", ds1, "dbo.rasmi"))
End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: I correct it myself error for being "dbo." before table after delete it code work correctly , you see now " jmcilhinney"